# Upgrading to Spring-batch 5.0.0: How to find/replace dependency on spring classes that appear to no longer exist?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We have code in our project that is originally based on an example from Dave Syer. We are updating to the latest release of spring-batch, and running into a problem with classes that this snip is dependent on that longer exist.

**POM extract**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-integration</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Code Extract**

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer;

@DependsOn("defaultBatchConfigurer")
@Configuration("org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration")
    public class SimpleBatchConfiguration extends AbstractBatchConfiguration {
```

The two imported classes don't appear to exist any more.

Please advise.

Comment: Start with reading the upgrade guide and release notes. Those generally tell you what to modify.

Comment: Can you add a link please?  My google-fu is not finding those.

Comment: The Spring Batch reference guide has all that information, that is readily available at https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch#learn

Comment: Thank you. I am reviewing the document now. If you post this as an answer I'll check it off.

Answer (score 2):

When upgrading step 1 (or at least step 1 when things are failing) is to read the upgrade guide and/or release notes.

For Spring Batch 5 the Reference Guide can be found [here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch#learn). It contains a Whats New section with hints/tips on what to upgrade/change.

For Spring Batch 5 a lot has changed to make configuration easier one of them being removing some configuration classes.